# Cannot get the .js file route

Tags: javascript, cucumber

Unable to get the .js file with Minium Developer. I have the route like in the example proyect but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

**Helper.js**

```
var helperFuntions = {

findExistingDataOnTable : function(cssSelector,query){

    var encontrado = $(cssSelector).matchingText(query);

    if (encontrado) {

        console.log("Superado");
    }else{

      console.log("No superado");
    }

  }

};
```

**ProyectoPrueba.js (not working, wrong import)**

```
var helperFuntions = require("modules/Helper/Helper.js");

When(/^Compruebo la existencia de "(.*?)"$/, function (query) {
   var cssTable = "\".ym-cbox\"";

helperFuntions.findExistingDataOnTable(cssTable, query);

});
```

**ProyectoPrueba.js (working, no import)**

```
When(/^Compruebo la existencia de "(.*?)"$/, function (query) {

    var found= $(".ym-cbox").matchingText(query);
  if (found) {
    console.log("Superado");

  }else{
    console.log("No superado");
  }

});
```

**Proyect hierarchy**

[image: Proyect hierarchy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must exclude the "modules" folder from the require path:

> require("Helper/Helper");

Also, the extension ".js" is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Your imports need to be absolute paths unless you're importing modules from a node_modules folder.

Let's say the `modules` folder is a sibling of the current folder you're importing it from.

In that case `require("modules/Helper/Helper.js");` should be `require("../modules/Helper/Helper.js");`